# Python SVN Bindings - ImportError: No module named svn

Tags: svn, python, trac, ubuntu-11.10

I have recently updated my server using `apt-get upgrade` and then suddenly trac started showing the following error message:

```
Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (Unsupported version control system "svn": No module named svn). Look in the Trac log for more information.
```

I have tried to install `python-subversion`, but that was installed already, so I have reinstalled it, but that didn't help.

```
~# python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import svn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named svn
```

I am running svn 1.7.4 on ubuntu 11.10 x64.

I do not know much about python. Why doesn't python find SVN anymore?

### Update

I have also tried installing the package `python-svn` using `sudo apt-get install python-svn`. That did not help either.

Comment: Are you using the aptitude managed version of Python?  Or is your `python` in a different place?  Try doing a `which python`.

Comment: @AndrewM. its aptitude's/dpkg python from the ubuntu repositories in `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: You can likely solve this by doing `pip install svn`, although it might be worth looking into why `svn` was not put into the correct place.

Comment: @AndrewM. `sudo pip install svn`
`Downloading/unpacking svn`
  `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement svn`
`No distributions at all found for svn`

Comment: @AndrewM. where does python expect those svn binding to be?

Comment: It should be in the site-packages directory of your Python installation.  It looks like `svn` isn't distributed via `pip`, so my suggestion was for not. :(  Have you tried removing (and purging) the python-svn package?

Comment: @AndrewM. the only such directory I could find was: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and that one is totally empty. `python-svn` wasn't installed when Mike first suggested it. But I have just tried to purge it and re-install it, in order to be sure, but it still didn't fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had similar problem on Ubuntu 12.04.  I upgraded subversion to 1.7.5 using WANdisco package.  This package binds svn to python2.6 and Ubuntu 12.04 has python2.7.

Here is a script which solved the problem on my side:

```
mkdir /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsvn
for f in /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.6/libsvn/*; do ln -s $f /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsvn/; done
for f in /usr/share/pyshared/libsvn/*; do ln -s $f /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsvn/; done

mkdir /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svn
for f in /usr/share/pyshared/svn/*; do ln -s $f /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svn/; done

mkdir /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libsvn
for f in /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.6/libsvn/*; do ln -s $f /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libsvn/; done
```

Best regards
Wojciech Dec

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for sharing this. It looks very promising. Will check it out asap.

Comment: Awesome! I've spent several hours trying different solutions but only this one has worked.

Comment: The newer WANdisco packages for Subversion 1.8 (released just last week) seem to fix this as well. They work fine on 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install them with apt-get

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-svn
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. See my update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The python module that python-svn installs is called pysvn. Apparently Trac needs a SWIG binding instead. See

- http://www.mail-archive.com/trac-users@googlegroups.com/msg18332.html
- http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion

Comment: Yeah I have installed the ubuntu package `python-subversion` with `apt-get install python-subversion` as mentioned in the question. And trac used to work. It's just that it suddenly stopped working because the package disappeared. Why did it disappear, and how can I get it back?

Answer (score -1):

For me the following helped:

```
apt-get install python-svn
apt-get install python-subversion
```

and then all worked fine.

Comment: OP already said reinstalling `python-subversion` didn't help, so you're posting this as answer to... rub it in?

Comment: i had the same problem .. and you have to install python-svn first and then python-subversion. Did you tried this?

Comment: @Kordi I have tried it… and it didn't help!